# Is there a way to make an object half opaque?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to make an object half opaque? I tried this:

```
renderer.material.color = new Color(255f, 255f, 255f, 0.5f);
```

But it just makes the item white and the textures are no longer showing.

I have tried using **Transparent/Bumped Specular** but that makes the object too transparent, even when I don't want the object transparent at the time.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make it transparent to look like the player is inactive during a character selection screen. When the player presses <kbd>A</kbd> they will go to full opaque and then can select their player.

Editor Mode:

[image: Editor]

Play Mode:

[image: Play]

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple things that I'd like to point out to you on this. First off, Unity's Color class is based on values from 0 to 1. So you have 255f in your RGB's, this is giving you what you expect now, but really it's just setting them to 1 in the constructor. So if you want colors in the future do:

```
new Color(rValue/255f, gValue/255f, bValue/255f, aValue/255f);
```

Just wanted to point that out while you were here.

So to your actual question, what you're doing with that line of code is you're saying, take the material attached to this object and make it completely white (if i'm wrong with 1,1,1 being white, someone please comment) and half transparent. But that doesn't apply to the object itself, that only applies to the material attached.

So if you want to modify the platform to be transparent, my recommendation is store both the transparent and non-transparent materials that you want on the script where you're changing which one is being used. Then in the code, instead of changing colors, change what material the renderer is using instead.

Hope this helps.